# Row children with equal heights can't update height correctly

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to have Row children with equal heights (and widths). In my example i have Text composables as children and they can have strings with varying length that can be updated at later point.
The problem is that when i set new string to be shown - the height of the children is not updated and the string is truncated. If the longer string is set initially the height of the children is correct. Maybe i am doing something wrong.
I just want when i set new longer string the two Texts to update their heights. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

```
@Composable
fun IssueWithRowHeight() {
    var longerText by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        delay(2000)
        longerText =
            "this is long text this is long text this is long text this is long text this is long text"
    }

    //If you use this and comment the launched effect the row has the correct height
//    var longerText by remember {
//        mutableStateOf("this is long text this is long text this is long text this is long text this is long text")
//    }

    Column {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(IntrinsicSize.Min),
        ) {
            //Radius
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .clickable {  }
                    .padding(PaddingValues(start = 16.dp, top = 8.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 8.dp))
            ) {
                Text(text = "short text")
            }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .clickable {  }
                    .padding(PaddingValues(start = 16.dp, top = 8.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 8.dp))
            ) {
                Text(text = longerText)
            }
        }

        //Just for reference that the string is actually updating..
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Red)
        ) {
            Text(text = longerText)
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229673431), it's fixed but not yet released at the moment.

As a temp workaround you can force remeasurements with `key`:

```
key(longerText) {
    // your Row with Text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
fun IssueWithRowHeight() {
    var longerText by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        delay(2000)
        longerText =
            "this is long text this is long text this is long text this is long text this is long text"
    }

    //If you use this and comment the launched effect the row has the correct height
//    var longerText by remember {
//        mutableStateOf("this is long text this is long text this is long text this is long text this is long text")
//    }

    Column {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight(),
        ) {
            //Radius
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .clickable {  }
                    .padding(PaddingValues(start = 16.dp, top = 8.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 8.dp))
            ) {
                Text(text = "short text")
            }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .clickable {  }
                    .padding(PaddingValues(start = 16.dp, top = 8.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 8.dp))
            ) {
                Text(text = longerText)
            }
        }

        //Just for reference that the string is actually updating..
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Red)
        ) {
            Text(text = longerText)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue with this solution is that the left and right rows now have different heights but i want to always be equal. It seems its bug in compose..